# 2 scripts need every frame from NOIR camera board at same time

Tags: python, raspicam, opencv

I have two opencv2/Python scripts running at the same time on the same Raspberry PI.

1. A streaming server script based on [this](https://github.com/berak/opencv_smallfry/blob/master/mjpg_serve.py), that outputs a live camera feed to the
   web
2. a motion detection script, that detects movement from a camera

Only one of these scripts can access the NOIR camera board at once, so I need a way of passing/sharing each frame gathered to the other script.

They both grab the frame from the NOIR camera board using opencv2's `rc,img = capture.read()`; so i'll have to remove that from one of them and somehow pass the img to the other script when rc is true.

As the camera frame rate is substantial, I don't think it's feasible to save the img (numpy array) to a file on a disc that they can both access; but I may be wrong!

I've been scratching my head and searching the net for examples on scripts that pass data, but alas i'm stuck.

How could I share a numpy array between two running python programs on the same Raspberry PI, and could someone kindly provide me some example code?

Comment: No chance of merging the two scripts?  Is the numpy (img) array a fixed size?

Comment: Iv'e tried to merge the scripts, but the streaming server script waits for a get request, prior to it starting the motion function (which iv'e placed around line 21). I cannot figure out a way to fool the server script that someone has accessed the stream; hence a different approach. I'm not sure if the numpy array is the same size each time. The camera view is constantly changing.

Comment: could I use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) to store the current img, in memory, and replace it with each new frame?

Comment: Plenty of methods.  Using shared memory (mmap) may be the most efficient.  You still need to know the size though.

Comment: how would I find out the size? is it the size of the resultant picture created from the numpy array? that's about 60Kb.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: iv'e just debugged the script in eclipse and looked at the numpy array, eclipse states its size as **int: 921600**